# Elasticsearch runtime error for query using sparse vectors

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Very recently Elasticsearch has implemented vector-based queries. This means that each document includes a vector as a field, and we can use a new vector to find a match in our corpus.

You can find [more information in this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#script-score-query-ex-request). The Elasticsearch team explain there how this should work, and even provide a query string:

```
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, doc['my_sparse_vector'])",
        "params": {
          "queryVector": {"2": 0.5, "10" : 111.3, "50": -1.3, "113": 14.8, "4545": 156.0}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have installed the latest Elasticsearch version, in particular, `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'` gives me this info:

```
"version" : {
"number" : "7.3.0",
"build_flavor" : "default",
"build_type" : "deb",
"build_hash" : "de777fa",
"build_date" : "2019-07-24T18:30:11.767338Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "8.1.0",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
}
```

I am working with the Python library `elasticsearch` (`elasticsearch_dsl` as well, but not yet for these queries). I can set up my Elasticsearch index, load documents and make queries. For example, this works:

```
query_body = {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Some text",
      "default_field": "some_field"
    }
  }
}

es.search(index=my_index, body=query_body)
```

However, when I try the same code for a query almost identical to the official example, it does not work.

My query:

```
query_body = {
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, doc['my_embedding_field_name'])",
        "params": {
          "queryVector": {"1703": 0.0261, "1698": 0.0261, "2283": 0.0459, "2263": 0.0523, "3741": 0.0349}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the sparse vector in the query is an example I made, making sure that the keys are found in at least the embedding vector of one of my documents (I am not sure this should be problematic, but in case).

The error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')
```

The error message does not help me a lot moving forward, and since this is a really new feature, I could not find other help online.

**Update**: Below is a more complete error message, produced when using curl for the query.

The core of the error is:

```
"type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason" : "Variable [embedding] is not defined."
```

The complete message is:

```
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "script_exception",
    "reason" : "compile error",
    "script_stack" : [
      "... (params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
      "                             ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script" : "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
    "lang" : "painless"
  },
  {
    "type" : "script_exception",
    "reason" : "compile error",
    "script_stack" : [
      "... (params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
      "                             ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script" : "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
    "lang" : "painless"
  }
],
"type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
"reason" : "all shards failed",
"phase" : "query",
"grouped" : true,
"failed_shards" : [
  {
    "shard" : 0,
    "index" : "test-index",
    "node" : "216BQPYoQ-SIzcrV1jzMOQ",
    "reason" : {
      "type" : "query_shard_exception",
      "reason" : "script_score: the script could not be loaded",
      "index_uuid" : "e1kpygbHRai9UL8_0Lbsdw",
      "index" : "test-index",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "... (params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
          "                             ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Variable [embedding] is not defined."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "shard" : 0,
    "index" : "tutorial",
    "node" : "216BQPYoQ-SIzcrV1jzMOQ",
    "reason" : {
      "type" : "query_shard_exception",
      "reason" : "script_score: the script could not be loaded",
      "index_uuid" : "n2FNFgAFRiyB_efJKfsGPA",
      "index" : "tutorial",
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "... (params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
          "                             ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Variable [embedding] is not defined."
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
"caused_by" : {
  "type" : "script_exception",
  "reason" : "compile error",
  "script_stack" : [
    "... (params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
    "                             ^---- HERE"
  ],
  "script" : "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, doc[embedding])",
  "lang" : "painless",
  "caused_by" : {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Variable [embedding] is not defined."
  }
} }, "status" : 400}
```

**Update 2**: My documents have this structure:

```
{"name": "doc_name", "field_1": "doc_id", "field_2": "a_keyword", "text": "a rather long text", "embedding": {"4655": 0.040158602078116556, "4640": 0.040158602078116556}}
```

**Update 3**: I am passing a mapping after creating the index, with:

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "field_1": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "field_2": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "text": {
        "type": "text"
    },
    "embedding": {
        "type": "sparse_vector"
    }
}
```

and this has removed an error complaining about too many fields (each key in the embedding was taken as a field). But the query error is the same.

Comment: You can probably see the full error message if you execute your query inside Kibana Dev Tools. The Python one is not of much use. Can you share it?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not working with Kibana on this project. I could look into that if it is really the way to go, tough. But I am quite inexperienced in all of this, so I bet it would take me a while to set it up.

Comment: Any chance to check the ES server logs in this case?

Comment: Nothing is trivial to me, but this sounds feasible, give me a few minutes and let me get back to you.

Comment: Using curl I was able to access a more detailed error message, which I have added to the question. Is this what you were looking for? I have also added an example of the json structure for my docs.

Comment: The exact error is `Variable [embedding] is not defined.` Which means that you need to reference a field you have inside the `embedding` dictionary, the `embedding` itself.

Comment: What you are saying makes me think that the embeddings are not correctly added to the documents (the embedding dictionary should be "the embedding itself"). Does this sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem we need to make sure that Elasticsearch understand the vector field ("embedding" in my case) is actually an sparse vector. For this, use:

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "reference": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "jurisdiction": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "text": {
        "type": "text"
    },
    "embedding": {
        "type": "sparse_vector"
    }
}
```

More details in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57611631/add-sparse-vector-as-field-in-elasticsearch/57623613#57623613).

There are two important things to note:

1. The quotes around the field name in the query are necessary.
2. [It is recommended to add +1 to the metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#vector-functions), to avoid negative values.

   `"source": "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, 
                                      doc['my_embedding_field_name']) + 1.0"`

Credit on these last points goes to jimczi from the Elastic Team (thanks!). See the [question on the forums here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/compile-error-when-using-sparse-vector-and-cosine-similarity/196474/2?u=pablo_gps).