# Add sparse vector as field in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

Recently Elasticsearch has allowed to use vectors and sparse vectors in queries. Following [their documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#script-score-query-ex-request), I come across an error (see [full details on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609746/elasticsearch-runtime-error-for-query-using-sparse-vectors)), essentially:

```
"type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason" : "Variable [embedding] is not defined."
```

It seems like "embedding" is not a successful field.

I am uploading my documents to Elasticsearch as follows:

1. I create a json file for each doc
2. I load json files in Python `db_object = json.load(fp)`
3. I pass these objetcs to Elasticsearch: `es.index(index=my_index, doc_type='sentence', id=db_object['name'], body=db_object)`

This is the structure of my json files (note that embedding is a dictionary, as it is an sparse vector).

```
{"name": "doc_name", "field_1": "doc_id", "field_2": "a_keyword", "text": "a rather long text", "embedding": {"4655": 0.040158602078116556, "4640": 0.040158602078116556}}
```

However, if I make a simple test query, embedding does not seem to work. Take this query structure:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "0.040158602078116556",
      "default_field" : "embedding"
    }
  }
}'
```

If I leave `embedding` in "default_field", no docs are found.

If I try `4655` as the field (note this is the key in the embedding dictionary corresponding to the number I have pasted in the query) nothing happens either.

However, if the field is `embedding.4655` the query works. To me, this seems like a clear sign that "embedding" is not being understood as a single field that is an sparse vector, but rather that the dictionary keys combine with "embedding" to form a collection of independent fields with a numeric value.

Another hint that something may not be right is that loading documents like this made Elasticsearch protest that there were too many fields, whereas I was expecting "embedding" to be one and only one field.

Am I correct? Is there a flaw in the way I am uploading my documents regarding this special field?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Elasticsearch has trouble inferring the correct type. It thinks that each key in the dictionary is a new field (embedding.key). So we need to provide a mapping specifying the types. In my case using the elasticsearch library in Python, after creating the index:

```
import requests

uri='http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping'

json_body="""{                    
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "reference": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "jurisdiction": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "text": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "embedding": {
            "type": "sparse_vector"
        }
    }
}""")  

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

requests.put(uri, headers=headers, data=json_body)
```